# Does Fetch's Response.body chunks correspond to HTTP chunks?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-chunked

I'm doing a Fetch-api request where the server replies using the HTTP chunked transfer encoding (with text data). I'm consuming the data using the `Response.body` as a stream.

I'm wondering: Is it safe to assume that the chunks generated by the stream correspond to the HTTP chunks? I've seen some questions[1-3] where this assumption seems to be made, but I cannot find anything about this in the spec.

[1] [JS Fetch use Chunked Transfer Encoding (translating curl to Fetch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264083/js-fetch-use-chunked-transfer-encoding-translating-curl-to-fetch) 
[2] [Consuming chunked data asyncrhonously in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206943/consuming-chunked-data-asyncrhonously-in-javascript/49211413#49211413) 
[3] [Read chunked binary response with Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828310/read-chunked-binary-response-with-fetch-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [comments from the author of the Fetch spec](https://freenode.logbot.info/whatwg/20190809#c2509829): *“no such guarantee… e.g., if there’s a delay after half of an HTTP chunk I’d expect two or so”*.